# Why does my python extending type AttrCache runs much slower than dict of python

Tags: python-2.7, performance, extending

I try to implement a new Type that has the same function of PyDictObject. But I found that it runs much slower than PyDictObject.
Here is my new Type of python extending.

```
typedef struct
{
    PyObject_HEAD
    PyDictObject *m; 
} AttrCache;

static Py_ssize_t
cache_length(AttrCache* self)
{
    return self->m->ma_used;
}

static PyObject *
cache_subscript(AttrCache* self, register PyObject*key)
{
    PyMappingMethods *m;
    m = self->m->ob_type->tp_as_mapping;
    return m->mp_subscript(self->m, key);
    //return dict_subscript(self->m, key);
}

static int
cache_ass_sub(AttrCache* self, PyObject *v, PyObject *w)
{
    if(w == NULL)
        return PyDict_DelItem((PyObject*)self->m, v);
    else
        return PyDict_SetItem((PyObject*)self->m, v, w);
}


static PyMappingMethods cache_as_mapping = {
    (lenfunc)cache_length,
    (binaryfunc)cache_subscript,
    (objobjargproc)cache_ass_sub,
};

int
Cache_contains(AttrCache* self, PyObject* key)
{
    return PyDict_Contains((PyObject*)self->m, key);
}

static PySequenceMethods cache_as_sequence = {
    0,                          /* sq_length */
    0,                          /* sq_concat */
    0,                          /* sq_repeat */
    0,                          /* sq_item */
    0,                          /* sq_slice */
    0,                          /* sq_ass_item */
    0,                          /* sq_ass_slice */
    Cache_contains,            /* sq_contains */
    0,                          /* sq_inplace_concat */
    0,                          /* sq_inplace_repeat */
};

static PyTypeObject AttrCacheType = {
    PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
        0,                       /* ob_size */
    "attrcache.AttrCacheType",         /* tp_name */
    sizeof(AttrCache),          /* tp_basicsize */
    0,                       /* tp_itemsize */
    0,                       /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                       /* tp_print */
    0,                       /* tp_getattr */
    0,                       /* tp_setattr */
    0,                       /* tp_compare */
    0,                       /* tp_repr */
    0,                       /* tp_as_number */
    &cache_as_sequence,                       /* tp_as_sequence */
    &cache_as_mapping,                       /* tp_as_mapping */
    0,                       /* tp_hash */
    0,                       /* tp_call */
    0,                       /* tp_str */
    0,                       /* tp_getattro */
    0,                       /* tp_setattro */
    0,                       /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT |
        Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE,   /* tp_flags */
    0,                       /* tp_doc */
    0,                       /* tp_traverse */
    0,                       /* tp_clear */
    0,                       /* tp_richcompare */
    0,                       /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    0,                       /* tp_iter */
    0,                       /* tp_iternext */
    0, //AttrCacheMethods,          /* tp_methods */
    0,                       /* tp_members */
    0,                       /* tp_getset */
    0,                       /* tp_base */
    0,                       /* tp_dict */
    0,                       /* tp_descr_get */
    0,                       /* tp_descr_set */
    0,                       /* tp_dictoffset */
    0,   /* tp_init */
    0,                       /* tp_alloc */
    AttrCacheNew,                       /* tp_new */
};
```

After I finished building the code above, I tested the performance. And the result was really bad. Here is my test code
import attrcache
    import time

```
pyDict = dict()
cDict = attrcache.AttrCache()


total = 10000000
keys = map(str, range(0, total))
print "init keys done"


start = time.time()
for key in keys:
    pyDict[key] = 1 

print "py init cost ", time.time() - start
start - time.time()
for key in keys:
    cDict[key] = 1 
print "c init cost ", time.time() - start
```

I was confused by the result. The py dict cost about 5 seconds while my c dict cost about 10 seconds.
Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: `start - time.time()` isn't resetting `start`, so you're counting both timings against your own object. Close-voting as typo.

Comment: Oh I am sorry. I reruned my code, and the result is fine. What a stupid question.